# Get clicked element with Jquery on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm trying to get the input element clicked on a form. I've two input type submit : one to save the form and the other to validate it. I need to know which button was clicked.

It's work for all browsers except Safari.

JS :

```
var target   = e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget || e.relatedTarget || document.activeElement;
    var buttonId = $(target).id;

    if (buttonId  == "opSave") {
        //doSomething
    } else if (buttonId  == "opCreate") {
        //doSomething
    }
```

HTML :

```
<input type='submit' onclick="void(0)" id="opSave" name='opSave' value='Save' />
<input type='submit' onclick="void(0)" id="opCreate" name='opCreate' value='Submit' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please go with JQuery approach of attaching click event like follows:

HTML:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="void(0)" id="opSave" name='opSave' value='Save' />
<input type='submit' onclick="void(0)" id="opCreate" name='opCreate' value='Submit' />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#opSave").click(function(){
        //doSomething
    });

    $("#opCreate").click(function(){
        //doSomething
    });
});
```

by this way you really don't have to bother about OS and browser